# How to get object by objectName in Qml from javascript?

Tags: qml, qt5

How to find object like in C++ with `findChild()`, but from javascript?

Comment: Why would you want to do this. You should not from C++, so you should not do it from JS. Maye you should rather ask, how you can solve a riddle without resorting to something `findChild()`ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As on the QML-side you usually have no access to the parent/child-relationships of the Qt/C++-side, but only to the visual parent/child-relationship, you will need to resort to C++.

You could e.g. create a object, that exposes a method which takes a `QObject`, and a name and calls the function `findChild` of this object.

If you only want to find a visual child, you might just implement a recursive bfs over the visual tree in JS and call this.

But as I said in my comment: If you need this, you probably messed up at some other place and should rather think about a way to do it, without `findChild()`. Using it is not recommended in C++, and is certainly not so in QML.
As it is a recursive search it will do its best in killing your performance. A UI contains easily a thousand elements and you would need to compare the `string`s all the time. Further you would lie about the dependencies by sneakingly access things you don't tell anyone you are depending on.

The `objectName` and the object that calls `findChild` might not be in the same logical part of your code, so it is easily broken, if someone might change this object or the objectName, and you are searching for a name that does not exist anymore.

Additionally, if you found an object with the name - and possibly the right type - there is still no guarantee, it is the right object, as the objectNames are not necessarily unique.

All in all, it is not the best design, to access objects like that - tough it might be possible.

> Disclaimer: I have not tried out my proposed solution, as I don't want to waste my time on it.

Comment: I want to change text property in the 'text' component. I have the following JSON `[{"id":"text1", "newText":"Pizza"},{"id":"text1", "newText":"Ramen"}]`. Where Id is the objectName and id of the text component. How to get text with this id?

Comment: I managed to do that by writing my own function `getObjectByName(name)`. Fortunately, all my objects were in a `container` so I could do a linear search with `itemAt(i).objectName` and `contentChildren`. Is it the _right_ way to do that?

Comment: *"If you need this, you probably messed up at some other place and should rather think about a way to do it"* I don't understand what is the issue with accessing elements programatically. This is one of the most basic things in software development. If you have let's say, 50 buttons, each one doing something similar, you might want to access them programatically in a for loop, etc. I think it's very narrow-minded and opinionated to say "if you're doing this way, you are probably doing it wrong"