# How to update textEdit properties in Qt Qml using dictionary from python?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml, pyside6

There are 4 textEdit's in my qml code. (There is no reason to leave a minimal code snippet of it, it can be the most basic ones...)

The format of the dictionary from **python** looks like this:

`{'textEdit1': ['999999', '999999', '999999', '999999', '999999', '999999'], 'textEdit2': ['Barbara ', 'Marieke', 'Ramses', 'Reatie', 'Gaby', 'Marthe'], 'textEdit3': ['Bijvank', 'Sassen', 'Man', 'Projecten', 'Knol', 'Noordijk'], 'textEdit4': ['', '', '', '', '', '']}`

The keys of the dictionary are exactly named as the id of the textEdit's.

The idea is to update the appropriate textEdits by id's (keys of the dictionary) and using the values of the dictionary as textEdit.text (text property of textEdit).

I wrote the following **javascript** function when the signal is received from python:

```
function onSendBackDictionaryTextEditData(myDictionary) {
    for (const key in myDictionary) {
        if (myDictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const value = myDictionary[key];
            //console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
            var target = `${key}`
            var textEditValues = `${value}`
            target.text = textEditValues
            console.log(textEditValues)
        }
    }
}
```

I can see all the keys and values received if i do **console.log**, but unfortunately I cannot update the text property. Can someone provide a minimal code snippet how to solve this issue?

I am using PySide6.

Here comes a minimal code snippet from the main.py file and from the main.qml file.

main.py:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal


class Main(QObject):

    onSendBackDictionaryTextEditData = Signal('QVariant')


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

    @Slot()
    def populatingTextEdit(self):
        textEditData = {'textEdit1': ['999999', '999999', '999999', '999999', '999999', '999999'], 'textEdit2': ['Barbara ', 'Marieke', 'Ramses', 'Reatie', 'Gaby', 'Marthe'], 'textEdit3': ['Bijvank', 'Sassen', 'Man', 'Projecten', 'Knol', 'Noordijk'], 'textEdit4': ['', '', '', '', '', '']}
        self.sendBackSwishQrTextEditData.emit(textEditData)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    main = Main()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("main", main)
    qml_file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"
    engine.load(qml_file)
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: bg
        color: "#000000"
        anchors.fill: parent

        RowLayout {
            id: rowLayout
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 640
            height: 202

            Rectangle {
                id: textEditrectangle1
                width: 200
                height: 200
                color: "#ffffff"
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true

                TextEdit {
                    id: textEdit1
                    text: qsTr("")
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    font.family: "Arial"
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: textEditrectangle2
                width: 200
                height: 200
                color: "#ffffff"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                TextEdit {
                    id: textEdit2
                    text: qsTr("")
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    font.family: "Arial"
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: textEditrectangle3
                width: 200
                height: 200
                color: "#ffffff"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                TextEdit {
                    id: textEdit3
                    text: qsTr("")
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    font.family: "Arial"
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: textEditrectangle4
                width: 200
                height: 200
                color: "#ffffff"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                TextEdit {
                    id: textEdit4
                    text: qsTr("")
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    font.family: "Arial"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Connections {
        target: main

        function onSendBackDictionaryTextEditData(myDictionary) {
            for (const key in myDictionary) {
                if (myDictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    const value = myDictionary[key];
                    const TextEditElement = `${key}`;
                    const TextEditValues = `${value}`;
                    console.log(`${key}, ${value}`)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        main.populatingTextEdit()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't access **Items** either by using their object names or `id`s as strings in QML-side [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065113/how-to-get-object-by-objectname-in-qml-from-javascript)]. However, you can try accessing **TextEdits** using the `children` property of their parents. Alternatively, you can use the `itemAtIndex()` function if they are contained within a `ListView` or any other model view. If you want more accurate suggestions, please provide a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of the your code.

Comment: As another idea, you can create a dictionary of items and their ids, like `property var dict: Object({item1:item1, item2:item2, item3:item3})`, and then access them using the `dict` object.

Comment: I have provided a minial exampel @smr.

Comment: I think it is better to use a ListView and just update the model using Python.

Comment: If you think that is better, then please provide a solution... @smr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have solved it see the updated qml code (thanks for the hint to create dict Object):**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property var dict: Object({
            textEdit1: textEdit1,
            textEdit2: textEdit2,
            textEdit3: textEdit3,
            textEdit4: textEdit4
        })

    Rectangle {
        id: bg
        color: "#000000"
        anchors.fill: parent

        RowLayout {
            id: rowLayout
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 640
            height: 202

            Rectangle {
                id: textEditrectangle1
                width: 200
                height: 200
                color: "#ffffff"
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true

                TextEdit {
                    id: textEdit1
                    text: qsTr("")
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    font.family: "Arial"
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: textEditrectangle2
                width: 200
                height: 200
                color: "#ffffff"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                TextEdit {
                    id: textEdit2
                    text: qsTr("")
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    font.family: "Arial"
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: textEditrectangle3
                width: 200
                height: 200
                color: "#ffffff"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                TextEdit {
                    id: textEdit3
                    text: qsTr("")
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    font.family: "Arial"
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: textEditrectangle4
                width: 200
                height: 200
                color: "#ffffff"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                TextEdit {
                    id: textEdit4
                    text: qsTr("")
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    font.family: "Arial"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Connections {
        target: main

        function onSendBackDictionaryTextEditData(myDictionary) {
            for (const key in myDictionary) {
                if (myDictionary.hasOwnProperty(key) && dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var textEdit = dict[key];
                    if (textEdit !== null && textEdit instanceof TextEdit) {
                        textEdit.text = myDictionary[key].join("\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        main.populatingTextEdit()
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be useful add some explanation of how you solved your problem, instead of just posting the fixed example.